# Li-Po batteries; Is random/incomplete charging hamful for the battery?

Tags: battery-charging, lipo

Sometimes when my Li-Po batteries are getting charged I have to leave home for some unforeseen  task. I never leave Li-Po batteries unattended while they are being charged. In such situations I am always in a fix whether to delay the task until the battery is completely charged or if it is fine to turn the charger off and resume when I am back?

Obviously I will not be using any such partially charged battery on the R/C aircraft and there will be no discharge event before I come back and restart the charge process.

Is this harmful for battery?

Charging Mode: **Balance**

Battery Type : **Li-Po**

Charger: It would be great if the answer applies generally to smart balancing chargers.

Comment: Evidence has shown LiPo battery life is doubled ( in cumulative  Ah) when kept between 50~75% all the time and are usually shipped with 66~75% SoC for this reason. But unbalanced cells can accelerate aging if one cell dips below 3.3V while others are 3.6 and still used.

Comment: Which would indicate that it should be fine to leave them partially charged and resume when you can? Those batteries won't be used until they are fully charged so the balance part shouldn't be a problem. And all of my chargers keep them at closely matched voltage levels even during the early stages of the process

Comment: correct... that is fine.. new good cells are balanced within 2%

Comment: Right now i have one battery on charge which has reached 3.71 on each of the 3 cells and I've got to go. I will take your advice and will assume its safe to stop the charger now and resume when I'm back

Comment: Reaching 3.71V 'on charge' suggests they were below 3.7V before charging. For best lifespan you should not let the resting voltage go below  3.7V, as this represents 90% discharge. You should cut your flight time back or (if possible) raise the low voltage cutoff point until the battery still has at least 3.7V per cell after flying. The danger of not fully charging is shorter flight time and therefore greater chance of over-discharging the battery.

Comment: @BruceAbbott thanks for your valuable advice. I was of the impression that it was fine to let it go down to 3.6 before landing and many people recommend a broader range of 3.4-3.7. Isn't 3.7 about half way through for a Li-Po cell instead of 90? I never let it go below 3.6

Comment: And im most certainly open to raising this limit to 3.7 if thats better. Batteries are more important than extra 2 minutes of flight

Comment: You're right, that's about 88% discharged. Thanks for your tip, Ill adjust my setup accordingly. Very helpful!